# refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have been struggling to get basic metrics from the CloudWatch agent. I've been getting this error and I have no idea what it means nor can I find resources online which talk much about it

> refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad: failed to get profile, metrics will be dropped until it got fixed

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/installing-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html) and have read through the documentation carefully. Again, the goal is just to read in some basic metrics from my EC2 instance to CloudWatch. Here are the steps I have followed:

- Followed instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html) "To create the IAM role necessary to run the CloudWatch agent on EC2 instances" and then assigned it to my instance.
- `wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb`

  - ami id is `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20190628 (ami-0cfee17793b08a293)`
- Install the `.deb` with command `sudo dpkg --install --skip-same-version ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb`

  - note `--install and --skip-same-version` is just `-i -E` as done in the docs
- generated a config.json with the wizard, located here `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json`. I pasted the contents under the error message below.
- modify the `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml` file to point to new credentials of `cwagent` (since not using root user) with the following:

```
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc# tail -n 4 common-config.toml 
#### BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK ####
[credentials]
shared_credential_file = "/home/cwagent/.aws/credentials"
#### END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK ####
```

- fetch config and start agent with `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json -s`

---

here's the error I'm seeing in the logs now, and I'm assuming why this is why I can't see any metrics

```
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs# tail -n 20 amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log 
2019/10/29 22:41:08 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
2019/10/29 22:41:08 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_config.json ...
2019/10/29 22:41:08 I! Detected runAsUser: cwagent
2019/10/29 22:41:08 I! Change ownership to cwagent:cwagent
2019/10/29 22:41:08 I! Set HOME: /home/cwagent
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! will use file based credentials provider 
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! cloudwatch: get unique roll up list []
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! Starting AmazonCloudWatchAgent (version 1.230621.0)
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! Loaded outputs: cloudwatch
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! cloudwatch: publish with ForceFlushInterval: 1m0s, Publish Jitter: 37s
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! Loaded inputs: disk mem
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! Tags enabled: host=ip-172-31-71-5
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! Agent Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"ip-172-31-71-5", Flush Interval:1s 
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z I! will use file based credentials provider 
2019-10-29T22:41:08Z E! refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad: failed to get profile, metrics will be dropped until it got fixed
2019-10-29T22:42:37Z E! refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad: failed to get profile, metrics will be dropped until it got fixed
2019-10-29T22:43:37Z E! refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad: failed to get profile, metrics will be dropped until it got fixed
2019-10-29T22:46:37Z E! refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad: failed to get profile, metrics will be dropped until it got fixed
2019-10-29T22:49:37Z E! refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad: failed to get profile, metrics will be dropped until it got fixed
2019-10-29T22:52:37Z E! refresh EC2 Instance Tags failed: SharedCredsLoad: failed to get profile, metrics will be dropped until it got fixed
```

and the config.json I used

```
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin# cat config.json
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
        "run_as_user": "cwagent"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "namespace": "TestNamespace",
        "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
            "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
        },
        "metrics_collected": {
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                    "mem_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDITS

I got it working after I removed the credentials modification

```
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc# tail -n 4 common-config.toml 
#### BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK ####
#[credentials]
#shared_credential_file = "/home/cwagent/.aws/credentials"
#### END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK ####
```

and after I went ahead and copied the config file to the default location it checks (even though the docs say you can pass the file name as I did).

```
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin# cp config.json /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin# cd ../etc/
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc# chown cwagent:cwagent amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json 
root@ip-172-31-71-5:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc# ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 cwagent cwagent 4096 Oct 30 22:05 amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cwagent cwagent  611 Oct 30 22:11 amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cwagent cwagent 1144 Oct 30 22:05 amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml
-rw-r--r-- 1 cwagent cwagent 1073 Oct 30 22:05 common-config.toml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appears to be related to **accessing tags** that are associated with Amazon EC2 instances.

The installation instructions you linked suggest creating an IAM Role with the `CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy` policy attached. This policy includes **permission to describe tags**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/AmazonCloudWatch-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

It would appear that the CloudWatch Agent on that server is not receiving such permissions, and is therefore unable to list the tags.

Therefore:

- Confirm that an **IAM Role has been created** and that it includes the `CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy` policy
- Confirm that this IAM Role has been **assigned to the Amazon EC2 instance** that is running the CloudWatch Agent
- If it is still failing, check whether there are any **credentials stored locally** on the instance that the Agent could be using instead of the IAM Role assigned to the instance

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'm looking forward to testing this out in the morning

Comment: I saw that the agent was trying to load from the default location `/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json` and not the file name I passed in the start command. I copied the config to the default location (and filename) with `cwagent` as owner/group (see question edit) and it worked after. Does that make sense to you? The config file flag appears to be broken on the amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl. I removed the change to common-config.toml as well, as apparently attaching the role to the EC2 instance is enough from what you said? It only worked after changing the config. I'm quite confused there

Comment: I'm guessing it was a combination of both (taking the credentials file out) and moving the config to the correct spot. I'll go ahead and give the green check - thank you! Would really appreciate your thoughts on why this worked if you're willing :)